# javascript - jshint possible strict violation error

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am developing a plugin of table export at client-side. Plugin works fine. But when I validated my code in jshint, it throws me an error saying possible strict violation. Below is the function:

```
function disableExport(){
        if(_(this).exportPlugin !== undefined){
            _(this).exportPlugin.setStyle('pointer-events', 'none');
            _(this).exportPlugin.find('.ebIcon').removeModifier('interactive','ebIcon');
            _(this).exportPlugin.find('.ebIcon').setModifier('disabled','','ebIcon');
        }else{
            console.log('ERROR!');
        }
    }
```

And it says: "If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its 'this' value will be undefined."

Complete code of plugin is available on https://jsfiddle.net/t47L8yyr/

**How do I resolve this ? any other solution than using `/*jshint validthis:true*/`**

Comment: "any other solution than using /*jshint validthis:true*/" — What's wrong with that?

Comment: @slezica — Also — if an OP doesn't like a particular answer for a duplicate question, that doesn't make it any less of a duplicate and they can post a bounty to encourage more answers to the duplicate … or they can ask a question which explains the particular circumstances which makes this question different.

Comment: I don't agree. This post shows a clear underlying confusion, which does not exist in the suggested duplicate and which I try to address in my answer below. A trained developer using modern javascript would never write this code, and we can help OP understand why. It is _not_ the same as the other question, it does not have the same answer, and OP rejects the answer presumably because he knows disabling the linter is only hiding his problem.

Comment: Linters are opinionated. Their output isn't gospel.

Answer (score 5):

Inside your `disableExport()` function, you make references to `this`. If you invoke the function normally...

```
disableExport()
```

... in [`strict` Javascript mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), `this` will be undefined. Outside strict mode, `this` will usually be the `window` object. So:

```
disableExport() // `this` will be `window`

"use strict"
disableExport() // `this` will be undefined
```

This is not good. If you want to target the `window` object, use it explicitly:

```
_(window).exportPlugin(...) // reference `window`, not `this`
```

If you're attempting to use `this` as a parameter to the function, invoking it
with [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it's much better to take an actual
parameter than to use `this`:

```
function disableExport(target) {
  if(_(target).exportPlugin !== undefined) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

You can then call `disableExport(window)` or any other `target`. It's usually
better to use `this` only when dealing with methods of an object, defined
in the `prototype` of a function, or through the [ES6 `class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. could you please show me this in  https://jsfiddle.net/t47L8yyr/ . I am assigning the plugin to `_(this).exportPlugin` after it's creation.